# How to sort cart items by date (the last modified cart item will be the first)?

Tags: php, date, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to order the cart contents by date, the last one added or modified must be displayed first. I tried reversing the order of the cart but its not working as expected. This is the code I tried:

```
//reorder cart
add_action('woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'wh_cartOrderItemsbyNewest');

function wh_cartOrderItemsbyNewest() {

    //if the cart is empty do nothing
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    //array to collect cart items
    $cart_sort = [];

    //add cart item inside the array
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) { print_r(WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key][0]);
        $cart_sort[$cart_item_key] = WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];
    }

    //replace the cart contents with in the reverse order
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = array_reverse($cart_sort);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cart items are already shown in cart by date added.

Then the last one added to the cart will be the first in the list.

**The problem arises when you change the quantity of a product in the cart**. In this case he would remain in his same position.

I thought of using a custom cart item data with the date of addition/modification but in this case it would create more lines of the same product.

I solved it with the [**Options API**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

I thought about creating/updating a realtime date option when:

- `woocommerce_add_to_cart` the product is added to the cart
- `woocommerce_cart_item_removed` the product is removed from the cart
- `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` the cart item quantity is updated *(increased or decreased)*

While the option is deleted when:

- `woocommerce_cart_emptied` the cart is emptied

> The sort will also be applied to the mini cart.

**The following function will create custom ordering of cart items** based on the `last_update_cart_item` option:

```
// sorts cart items by modification date
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'sorts_cart_items_by_modification_date' );
function sorts_cart_items_by_modification_date() {

    // only if the cart is not empty
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    // only if the "last_update_cart_item" option exists
    if ( ! $last_update = get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $cart_sort = array();
    $cart_item_content = array();

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // gets the update date of the cart item
        $cart_sort[$cart_item_key] = $last_update[$cart_item_key];
        // gets the contents of the cart item
        $cart_item_content[$cart_item_key] = WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];
    }

    // sorts the cart items by descending date (the last modified will be the first)
    array_multisort( $cart_sort, SORT_DESC, WC()->cart->get_cart() );

    // creates the new sorting with the contents of the cart items
    foreach ( $cart_sort as $key => $value ) {
        $sorted[$key] = $cart_item_content[$key];
    }

    // update cart contents with custom sorting
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $sorted;
    
}
```

While the following functions will update the `last_update_cart_item` option **when the product is added, changed or removed from the cart**:

```
// update the "last_update_cart_item" option with the date the product was added to the cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'after_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function after_woocommerce_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    $last_update = array();
    if ( get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' ) ) {
        $last_update = get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' );
    }
    // set the updated date of the cart item
    $last_update[$cart_item_key] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    update_option( 'last_update_cart_item', $last_update );

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// when the cart item is removed, it also removes the cart item key from the "last_update_cart_item" option
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'after_woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 10, 2 );
function after_woocommerce_cart_item_removed( $cart_item_key, $cart ) {
    if ( $last_update = get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' ) ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $cart_item_key, $last_update ) ) {
            // removes the cart item key from the "last_update_cart_item" option
            unset( $last_update[$cart_item_key] );
            update_option( 'last_update_cart_item', $last_update );
        }
    }
}

// when the quantity of the cart item updates, sets or updates the date
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'update_cart_item_data_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 10, 4 );
function update_cart_item_data_after_cart_item_quantity_update( $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity, $cart ) {
    $last_update = array();
    if ( get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' ) ) {
        $last_update = get_option( 'last_update_cart_item' );
    }
    // updates the date of the cart item whose quantity has been changed
    $last_update[$cart_item_key] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    update_option( 'last_update_cart_item', $last_update );

}

// when the cart is empty delete the "last_update_cart_item" option
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_emptied', 'after_woocommerce_cart_emptied', 10, 1 );
function after_woocommerce_cart_emptied( $cart ) {
    // delete the "last_update_cart_item" option
    delete_option( 'last_update_cart_item' );
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*